# JAVA, Find the child process id from Parent process id

Tags: java, pid, child-process

I am invoking a command which spawns two processes

```
Process p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("<...>\bin\\script");
```

" process 1 with the pid 1234, process 2 with the ppid 1234, pid 3456 "

I can get the process id(1234) by the following code :

```
String name = ManagementFactory.getRuntimeMXBean().getName();
String processId = name.split("@")[0];
System.out.println("Process ID for this app =  " + processId);
```

But I cant get the other process's id (3456). Is there a way to extract all the child process ids from a process?

Comment: You might want to find it from the `Process` object. See e.g. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4750470/how-to-get-pid-of-process-ive-just-started-within-java-program

Comment: Could [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/10124625/5128464) help you (windows specific solution)?

Comment: @vlp I have gone through the link you provided.. but need it platform independent. Thanks.