# How to resolve InaccessibleObjectException for Field.setAccessible in JDK 17?

Tags: java, reflection

With JDK 17, it's not possible anymore to make a field accessible using reflection, at least not for `java.lang`-classes. Following snippet:

```
final Process process = new ProcessBuilder().directory(new File("d:/temp")).command("cmd.exe").start();
final Field handleField = process.getClass().getDeclaredField("handle");
handleField.setAccessible(true);
```

fails with:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.reflect.InaccessibleObjectException: Unable to make field private final long java.lang.ProcessImpl.handle accessible: module java.base does not "opens java.lang" to unnamed module @254989ff
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.AccessibleObject.checkCanSetAccessible(AccessibleObject.java:354)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.AccessibleObject.checkCanSetAccessible(AccessibleObject.java:297)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Field.checkCanSetAccessible(Field.java:178)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Field.setAccessible(Field.java:172)
```

Is there a way to work around this problem?

Comment: maybe this helps: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41265266/how-to-solve-inaccessibleobjectexception-unable-to-make-member-accessible-m

Comment: "How to solve [...]": by rewriting your code so that this is no longer required.

Comment: @ThomasKläger What exactly do you suggest to get the launched process' handle (to being able to kill the whole process tree)?

Comment: @ThomasS. by using the methods that Java supports since Java 9 (see the last code fragment at https://stackoverflow.com/a/10124625, using `ProcessHandle`)

Answer (score 9):

As [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41265267/241453) points out, one solution is to add following VM option:

```
java --add-opens java.base/java.lang=ALL-UNNAMED
```

Comment: This didn't work for maven option added as <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <argLine>--add-opens java.base/java.lang=ALL-UNNAMED</argLine>
</configuration> #mstrap

Answer (score 0):

Alternative Java 17 solution:

````
Field field = MyClass.class.getDeclaredField("myField");
MethodHandle getter = MethodHandles.lookup().unreflectGetter(field);
Object value = getter.invokeExact(new MyClass()); ```
````

Comment: This method doesn't seem to work and produces an `IllegalAccessException` in contrast to the approach via CMD line argument mentioned above.