# How to get "default" random object (or seed) in Java?

Tags: java, random, random-seed

I know that I can create Random object and set seed for the object like this:

```
Random random = new Random();
random.setSeed(seed);
```

But what if I can't create Random object? What if I have to use Math.random()?

I know that Math.random() creates Random object behind the scene.

So the question is there any way to get the Random object created by Math.random and set seed for the object or at least get seed that the object is using?

Comment: Always possible to extract Random object via reflection. Look at `Math.RandomNumberGeneratorHolder.randomNumberGenerator`

Comment: @gdomo Reflection is not the answer.

Comment: @gdomo it's private in Math.

Comment: use `setAccessible(true)` as usual for private fields

Comment: May I ask why you want to do that? Questions such as this are often the result of an [XY problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XY_problem)

Comment: @OldDogProgrammer well, it's not real work task. Just a part of one contest problem that I'm trying to solve. In other words, the question is it possible to predict next Math.random() value?

Answer (score -1):

`Math.random` is just a shortcut that uses an internal `Random` object. If you need or want control over the seed, just don't use it, and use a `(Secure)Random` you create yourself. It has the same features as `Math.random`, plus quite a few more.

Comment: I know it. The question is what if I can't create my own Random object? Let's say I have such a limitation. I believe I mentioned it in my initial question.

Comment: Why wouldn't you be able to create it? If old code is using `Math.random`, refactor it.

Comment: In other words, "Can I" is the wrong question. The right question is "Should I?", and the answer is "no".

Comment: Let's say I have a code that pick a random number using Math.random() and I can't touch the code. I need to guess the number.

Comment: @chaika_sv Others have already told you it can be done using reflection. I've already told you how to do it properly. What more do you want?

Comment: Reflection doesn't work for me. Trying this  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72982904/how-to-resolve-inaccessibleobjectexception-for-field-setaccessible-in-jdk-17