# Alternate for C# System.Windows.Forms.SendKeys.Send method in java

Tags: c#, java, keyboard, operating-system, keyboard-shortcuts

I would like to know is there any alternates for the following C# function in java..

```
System.Windows.Forms.SendKeys.Send()
```

Basically i am doing an application that should send key presses to system that is for other applications.

like if i send

```
Ctrl+C Value
```

to the system, it should copy the selected content (in any other application, not in my application)

any other suggestions are also welcome

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Java Robot.keypress(int keycode)

java doc : http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/Robot.html

Comment: Thanks for your reply. i went through this earlier but got a doubt whether this will for other applications..

Comment: @user3260179 It should. Assuming it is calling the Windows API then it should. If not, you can always call Windows API by yourself or use some 3rd party scripting libraries.

Comment: I will try the robots and get back to you

Answer (score 0):

Your best bet will probably be to call the Windows API directly.

The call you would be using would be "PostMessage" from the windows API.

See the following link for a reference on how to call the Windows native API,

[How to use winapi functions in java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2172520/how-to-use-winapi-functions-in-java)